# WPF App StartupUri is not found when using linked source files

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF solution which produces two executables. Both projects use the same startup form.

In my newer project I access all the form sources using linked source files within a folder called "Forms" (which also has the same name on the original project).

Both projects have an App.xaml containing

```
<Application ...             
    StartupUri="Forms/frmMenu.xaml"
    Startup="App_Startup"/>
```

The following IOException is raised at runtime (but only for the new project):
    System.IO.IOException was unhandled
      HResult=-2146232800
      Message=Cannot locate resource 'forms/frmmenu.xaml'.
      Source=PresentationFramework

Is this a WPF bug?

n.b. The actual path is .../Forms/frmMenu.xaml is the lowercase an issue?

Comment: Your exception has lowercase name for the form it is trying to locate (frmmenu) so that maybe the issue. It should be looking for frmMenu with a capital M.

Comment: In WPF you should say `Window` rather than `Form`.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou  CodingYoshi.

It turns out that the inappropriately named StartupUri is not a Uri it is a file path. So the value should have been:

```
StartupUri="Forms\frmMenu.xaml"
```

Interestingly, the original project used
 StartupUri="Forms/frmMenu.xaml" and worked fine.

When I switched the original to use StartupUri="Forms\frmMenu.xaml" it continued to work.

I guess the backslash is just for linked files.